# Show that if f(z) is analytic then f(z) converges to a constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi All;

I am trying to do the following question. This is not for homework, but for my own education/pleasure.

Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic on $\{$ $z$ $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$ : $\mid z\mid > 1 \}$ such that $\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{f(z)}{z} = 0$. Show that there is a $c$ $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$ 
with $\lim_{z\to\infty}\ f(z) = c$.

If we define $g(z)$=$\frac{f(z)}{z}$, then $g(z)$ should have a singularity at $z=0$.The order of this singularity would be $1$, therefore making it a simple pole. But it does not tell us anything about $f(z)$. Other than this fact, I am really stuck.

Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z) = c$?

Comment: If a point is a *removable singularity* then it can't be a pole ...unless poles of degree zero are allowed by definition, which I'd find weird.

Comment: Does this then mean that $g(z)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$?

Comment: Do we know anything about $f(z)$ on the set $\{$ $z$ $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$ : $\mid z\mid \leq 1 \}$? Could we say that $g(z)$ is analytic on this set except on a small neighborhood of $0$?

Answer (score 1):

Look at $g(z) = f(1/z)$. Then you have $\lim_{ z \rightarrow 0} z g(z) = 0$. What does this say about the singularity of $g(z)$ at $z = 0$?

Comment: In this case,  $g(z)$ would have a pole at $z=0$, i.e. it would be an isolated singularity?

Comment: I meant, of the three types of isolated singularities (poles, removable, essential) in this case, $g(z)$ would have a pole at $z=0$. I sort of see where you are going at here. On page 129 of Ahlfors, he talks about treating $f(\infty)$ as an isolated singularity on the Riemann Sphere. But I am not sure why $\lim_{z\to\ 0}zg(z) = 0$? Is it because $g(z)$=$f(\frac{1}{z})$. So $\lim_{z\to\ 0}z$frac{f(\frac{1}{z})}{z}=